# Access Model List Used in Another Model to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-5.0

I have the following code. I want to use the objects of List in my view where I have used DTOQuestions

```
//My Model Question
public class Question
{
    public int Question_Id { get; set; } 
    public string Question_Title { get; set; }
    public List<Reply> Reply_List { get; set; }
}

//My 2nd Model Answer
public class Reply
{
    public int Reply_Msg { get; set; }
    public int Attachment_Id { get; set; }
}

//View
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        foreach(var replylbl in item.Forum_Reply_List)
        {
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(replymodel => replylbl.Reply_Msg)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(replymodel => replylbl.Attachment_Id)</th>
        }
    }


    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
       <td>
        @foreach (var reply in item.Forum_Reply_List){@Html.DisplayFor(modelReply => reply.Reply_Msg)}
    </td>
    <td>
        @foreach (var reply in item.Forum_Reply_List){@Html.DisplayFor(modelReply => reply.Attachment_Id)}
    </td>
```

I have these two models and following view. Now I want to access Answer (reply) model's objects in my view which has model type Question
But in view I am unable to display headers for those columns..

Comment: i guess you should create a ViewModel for your View, that contains both objects model, Question and Answer.

Comment: And where is your problem? Show your view, please.

Comment: What you mean by answer? If it is reply then you will can fetch all the reply related to question and bind with the Reply_List property , so it will available at the view and then you can iterate through foreach loop.

Comment: @DeepakJ Yes answer is Reply...!! I am unable to access them in view with foreach. Here is what i tried in view...in upper window

Comment: @vortex I have inserted view code.

Comment: try with `@Html.DisplayFor(reply => reply.Reply_Msg)`